# Pass X-API-Key to curl header

Tags: linux, curl

My orginal request is below and it was ok:

```
curl -X GET --header 'X-API-Key: myapikey' 'myurl'
```

But i want to receive X-API-Key from ~/.netrc file:

```
machine myhostname 
    login administrator
    password myapikey
```

My second request is:

```
curl -v -X GET 'myurl'
```

The error below:

```
{"status": 401, "detail": "No authorization token provided"}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to pass X-API-Key to curl command by using `.netrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login and password in .netrc will be add to "Basic Authorization".

[.Netrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRQcD.png)